# Can Someone explain about redis and lodash modules in node

Tags: node.js

I am new to learning node.js .I read redis module in one project.But i didnt get any sense by seeing documentation.Can anyone please explain briefly about redis and lodash module.I want What is the use of redis and lodash modules..!!!!!!

Thanks for Advance

Comment: Redis & Lodash are two completely different things. Redis is a DB while lodash is for manipulating data using the built in functions

Comment: @james,yes i know those two are different to each other.But i want to know about those two modules man.Thansk for response

Comment: You should search them up on Google! Read a couple articles, watch a couple videos, and write a bit of code!

Comment: Whenever you see an unknown module (which you will see manny times), look up that package on npm, from there you can get the github repo and website url of that package which will contain examples and simple explanations about that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Redis (http://redis.io/)**

Is a in memory data structure store. Can be used as database, cache or message broker...

**Lodash (https://lodash.com/):**

JavaScript utility library: 
Helps you working with array, strings, collections, functions, date, .....

Comment: Can u explain perfect use of Redis module .??? MA gone through the doc but lot of confusions.can u elaborate the use of Redis.???

Comment: You should not search problems to search a tool... search a tool which solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

**LODASH :**

Lodash makes JavaScript easier by taking the hassle out of working with arrays, numbers, objects, strings, etc.
Lodash’s modular methods are great for:

1.Iterating arrays, objects, & strings

2.Manipulating & testing values

3.Creating composite functions

**REDIS :**

Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as database, cache and message broker.Its well known for cache server because of its speed.

f9or rdis doc: http://redis.io/

redis for node please go through it, u will get an idea about it

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-redis-node-js/

Redis basically doesnt support for windows.To download redis for windows :

Download the latest Redis .msi file from

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases

after installation. The redis service is installed, we can operate it from Service manager

THANK YOU..^